# Alternating table row background colors on a dynamic table

Tags: php, css

I have a table generated by a `foreach` loop.

Before the loop, I create `$iteration = 0`. At the beginning of the loop it increments `$iteration`.

Then I do this:

```
if($iteration % 2 == 0) { 
  $greyRow = 'css for a grey row'; 
}
```

I've only three rows, at max, to test this with, but it seems that it greys the 2nd and 3rd row under the current rule, rather than only the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you also need to have an `else` statement to set back to the other color on the odd rows.  Not quite sure without seeing more of your implementation.

```
if ($iteration % 2 == 0) {
    $css = 'css for a grey row';
} else {
    $css = 'css for a white row';
}
```

Comment: This works, but the code is a little "fat" for a template (imho).  I personally try to make my templates as lean with php code as possible

Answer (score 4):

This following will add a `grey` class for even rows.

```
echo '<tr', ($iteration & 1 ? ' class="grey"': ''), '>';
```

#### Note

This uses a [bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It's a micro-optimization but far more optimal than the modulus operator (although notoriously used in these cases).

Also, I would encourage you to utilize CSS classes for even and odd rows versus inline styles or just toggling a single class (i.e. `grey`).

```
echo '<tr class="', ($iteration & 1 ? 'even': 'odd'), '">';
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to do this kind of thing..

```
<style type="text/css">
.odd td { background: #eee; }
</style>
<tr class="<?= ++$iteration % 2? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">....</tr>
```