# Table tr background color change

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to make in sort that odd `<tr>` and even `<tr>` have different color for easier reading.

Here's my code:

```
$show_res = mysql_query($show_query);
while ($show_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_res)){
$rc++;
if (($rc > 1)){
    $tr = '#cccccc';
} else {
    $tr = '#ffffff';
}?>
  <tr style="background-color:<?php echo $tr ;?>">
```

It doesn't work, am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958471/alternating-table-row-background-colors-on-a-dynamic-table

Comment: Do you have something else that would be setting the background-color? Like the TD elements? or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use modulo %

Some examples:

- 5 % 2 = remainder is 1
- 4 % 2 = remainder is 0
- 6 % 2 = remainder is 0
- 9 % 2 = remainder is 1

So based on whether the remainder is 1 or 0 you change the color. And you want the `<tr>` element to be a part of your loop as that's constantly being changed from one color or the other, back and forth.

```
$show_res = mysql_query($show_query);
while ($show_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_res))
{
    $rc++;
    if ($rc % 2 == 1)
    {
        $tr = '#cccccc';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $tr = '#ffffff';    
?>
  <tr style="background-color:<?php echo $tr ;?>">
<?
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Warface well, give me my points then yo. I only help people on this site to get points that are arbitrarily created. (Green check) :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
$show_res = mysql_query($show_query);
while ($show_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_res)){
$rc++;
if (($rc > 1)){
    $tr = 'odd';
} else {
    $tr = 'even';
}?>
  <tr class="<?php echo $tr ;?>">
```

CSS

```
.odd td { background-color: #FFF; }
.even td { backgorund-color: #F6F6F6; }
```

Use CSS and set the color background to the TD not the TR element.

Answer (score 1):

As this is strictly Display, I would recommend doing is using Javascript, not PHP.

Look how simple it can be:
http://paragasu.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/alternate-table-row-color-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `$rc=0;` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having appears to be that you're not resetting $rc++ after you've incremented it.  Try setting it to 0 then reset it after you've incremented it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$show_res = mysql_query($show_query);
while ($show_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_res))
{
       if ( isset($k) and $k==1)
       {
             echo '<tr class="EvenTableRows">';
             $k=0;
        } else {
             echo  '<tr class="OddTableRows">'; 
             $k=1;
        }

      ..... more statement

}
```